# Python - use a list of names to find exact match in pandas column containing emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, pandas, email

I have an Excel file containing a free-form text column (that sometimes is structured like an email), where I need to **find all first and last names and add an extra columns saying TRUE/FALSE** to these fields. I do not need to extract matched data (i.e. note it down in an adjacent column), although that could be an advantage.

**NB**: I do not know the names that I need to find, so it is pure guesswork. I have a list of registered first names with 40k+ entries, as well as a list of most common last names with another 16k+ entries.

So far, I managed to filter out roughly 10000 rows out out ~20000 row file, although my solution contains a lot of false positives. *e.g.* some rows marked TRUE for first names, contain text like "**Det er OK.**", where Python (I assume) merges the entire text together and extracts any matching substing to a name from a list, in this case I guess that could be "**t er O**" or "**r OK**", since my list has names "**Tero**" and "**Rok**" (although the case does not match and it combines letters from 2/3 separate words, which is not what I want)... Weirdly enough, this is **NOT TRUE** for the same text written in lowercase and without "**.**" at the end, i.e. "**det er ok**", which is marked as FALSE! P.S. there are unfortunatelly few names in the emails that are written in lowercase letters and not sentence case as it should be...

**Sample email** (with names Thomas, Lars, Ole, Per):

> Hej *Thomas*,
>
> De 24 timer var en af mange sager som vi havde med til møde med *Lars* og *Ole*. De har godkendt den under dette møde.
>
> Mvh. *Per*

**My code:**

```py
# Import datasets and create lists/variables
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

namesdf = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name='Alle Navne')
names = list(namesdf['Names'])

lastnamesdf = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheet_name='Frie Efternavne')
lastnames = list(lastnamesdf['Frie Efternavne'])


# Import dataset and drop NULLS
df = pd.read_excel(r'Entreprise Beskeder.xlsx', sheet_name='dataark')
df["Besked"].dropna(inplace = True)


# Compare dataset to the created lists to match first and last names
df["Navner"] = df["Besked"].str.contains("|".join(names)) # Creates new column and adds TRUE/FALSE for first names
df["Efternavner"] = df["Besked"].str.contains("|".join(lastnames)) # Creates new column and adds TRUE/FALSE for last names


# Save the result
writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

**I would appreciate any suggestions that could potentially improve my code** and reduce manual work that it will take to filter out all of these false positive cells that I found! I think the best case scenario would be a case sensitive piece of code that finds only the specific name without merging the text together. Also, it would be great if I could extract a specific string that Python finds a match in, as that would reduce manual work when trying to figure out why exactly a specific block of text was marked as TRUE. All in all, every suggestion is welcome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the thing you're trying to do is *somewhat* insane. With 40k first names to search for, false positives are inevitable. At the same time, with only 40k names, false *negatives* are also inevitable. [People's names are untidy](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/); hopefully you have plans to accommodate. Even when you get *correct* matches for a "first" and "last" name, as your example email shows, there's no guarantee that they'll be the first and last names *of the same person*.

Maybe someone with experience in natural-language-processing AI would be able to solve your problem in a robust way. More likely you've resigned yourself to a solution that simply *isn't* robust. You still pretty definitely need case-sensitivity and "whole word" matching.

I'm not convinced by the example you give of a false positive. The pandas function you're using is regex-based. `r'tero'` does *not* match `'t er o'`; it *does* match `'interoperability'`. With name lists as long as you're using, it seems more likely that you over-looked some other match in the email in question. I would kinda expect just a few of the names to be responsible for the majority of false-positives; outputting the matched text will help you identify them.

- Case-sensitive regex matching should be the default.
- I think `\b...\b` as a regex pattern will give the kind of "whole word" matching you need.
- [pandas.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) will do the capturing.

Given the size of your datasets, you may be a bit concerned with the performance. Or you may not, it's up to you.

I haven't tested this at all:

```py
# Import datasets and create lists/variables
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from typing import Iterable

# Document, sheet, and column names:
names_source_file = 'names.xlsx'
first_names_sheet = 'Alle Navne'
first_names_column = 'Names'
last_names_sheet = 'Frie Efternavne'
last_names_column = 'Frie Efternavne'
subject_file = 'Entreprise Beskeder.xlsx'
subject_sheet = 'dataark'
subject_column = 'Besked'
output_first_name = 'Navner'
output_last_name = 'Efternavner'
output_file = 'PythonExport.xlsx'

# Build (very large!) search patterns:
first_names_df = pd.read_excel(names_file, sheet_name=first_names_sheet)
first_names: Iterable[str] = namesdf[first_names_column]
first_names_regex = '''\b{}\b'''.format('|'.join(first_names))
last_names_df = pd.read_excel(names_file, sheet_name=last_names_sheet)
last_names: Iterable[str] = lastnamesdf[last_names_column]
last_names_regex = '''\b{}\b'''.format('|'.join(last_names))

# Import dataset and drop NULLS:
data_frame = pd.read_excel(subject_file, sheet_name=subject_sheet)
data_frame[subject_column].dropna(inplace=True)

# Add columns for found first and last names:
data_frame[output_first_name] = data_frame[subject_column].str.extract(
    first_names_regex,
    expand=False
)
data_frame[output_last_name] = data_frame[subject_column].str.extract(
    last_names_regex,
    expand=False
)

# Save the result
writer = ExcelWriter(output_file)
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

One obvious problem that I still haven't talked about is that there may be multiple name matches in a given subject. Assuming that you care about multiple matches, you can probably do something with [extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! If I use `str.extract(first_names_regex, expand=False)` then I get `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`, which points to `expand=False`. However, I have tried to use your code with `str.contains`, which unfortunately gives the exact same match of rows as it did with my original code.
I have also tried `str.extractall` method, which for some reason gives me a `ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups` pointing to `(first_names_regex)` part of `extractall` method...

Comment: Ah. Most tools that use regex capture groups count _the whole regex_ as "capture group zero". It sounds like these pandas functions aren't doing that, which is obnoxious I guess. Try adding a [capture group](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html?wlr=1)? `first_names_regex = '''\b({})\b'''.format(...)`

Answer (score 2):

To see what is being matched, use `apply()` with a python function:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(pat)

def search(item):
    mo = regex.search(item)
    if mo:
        return mo[0]
    else:
        return ''

df.msg.apply(search)
```

This will yield a Series with the names that matched or '' if there isn't a match.